# C# Formatting Long variable as String

Tags: c#, variables, string-formatting

I'm trying to take a variable (long), and convert it to a string, such that:

```
150 -> 150
1500 -> 1,500
1234567 -> 1,234,567
```

I know this shouldn't be difficult, but so far, I've only been able to find two different solutions, and they're not giving me the output I want:

This: `String.Format("{0:n}", *long variable*.ToString())`

gives me: `2000 -> 2000`

and this: `*long variable*.ToString("N" or "N0")`

gives me: `2000 -> 2000.00`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone commented the correct syntax on an answer that was deleted, so for the sake of anyone reading this in the future, here is what works:

`String.Format("{0:#,##0}", *long variable*)`

Answer (score 3):

Either of these work fine

`string.Format("{0:n0}", someNumber);`

`string.Format("{0:#,##0}", someNumber);`

---

These can be used with `ToString()` as well, (e.g. `someNumber.ToString("n0");`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0,0}", 1500L); // Writes '1,500' (exact output depends on culture)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give the formatting you want:

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", number);
```